# Print data from dynamic table in JSF

Tags: jsf-2

I have a screen with dynamic table contains inputtext feild and selectneMenu beside it there's a (+) button, when the user should press that button the form should add another extra row below it
,I want to print on console(Eclipse) the data that user will enter and i want to add a validation for  (+) button that user cant add new row until the user enter data in all cells in the previous row
 Iam a newbie for jsf programming.Can someone tell me a basic example.

Answer (score 0):

You may use f:setPropertyActionListener with h:commandButton to get the values of current row in your backing bean. And in Backing bean you may apply the validation to check values of inputtext and selectOneMenu. If values are non empty you can add new object (row) to your list like below :

JSF Code:

```
<h:datatable id="dt" var="element" value="#{bean.list}">
<h:column>
<h:inputText value="#{element.inputVal}" > </h:inputText>
</h:column>
<h:column>
<h:selectOneMenu value="" > </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:column>
<h:column>
     <h:commandButton value="Plus Button" action="#{bean.addRow}">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{element}" target="#{bean.selectedRow}" />
    </h:commandButton> 
</h:column>
</h:datatable>
```

Bean Code :

```
   public void addRow()
        {
           if(validateEmptyRow(selectedRow)
           {
            A a = new A();
            list.add(a);
           }
          else
          {
           //Print Validation Message
          }
        }

    public boolean validateEmptyRow(A selectedRow){

        boolean flag = true;
        if(null == selectRow.getInputVal()){
          flag = false;
        }
        //similary validate null value for selectOneMenu and return boolean value false if any of the two is having null or empty value
        return flag; 
    }

//define getter setter for selectedRow, list etc
```